# How to convert CJS import/export syntax to ESM?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, commonjs

How do I rewrite `module.exports = model('users', userSchema)` CJS export to ESM export syntax? How to import it to another file (with ESM syntax)?

This is how I tried to convert this line to ESM export syntax:

```js
// 1
export { model('users', userSchema) }
// 2
model('users', userSchema)
export { model }
```

And import:

```js
// 1
import { User } from '../file.js'
// 2
import User from '../file.js'
// 3
import * as User from '../file.js'
```

But nothing works. I end up getting an error:

> SyntaxError: The requested module `../file.js` does not provide an export named `default` or `User`

Comment: Suggest you start from here: https://dev.to/iggredible/what-the-heck-are-cjs-amd-umd-and-esm-ikm

It's not that fresh but you definitely will learn something from here

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue myself:

Before (CJS):

```js
module.exports = model('users', userSchema)
const User = require('../models/user_model.js')
```

After (ESM):

```js
export default model('users', userSchema)
import User from '../models/user_model.js'
```